# linq order by taking really long time

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, csv

I am kind of stuck again as I am unable to understand this.

So I have a class named `CSVItem`:

```
public class CSVItem
{
    public int SortedAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int SNO { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int Year
    {
        get
        {
            if (Date.Month > MainWindow.fiscalMonth)
            {
                return Date.Year+1;
            }
            return Date.Year;
        }
    }
    public int StaticCounter { get { return 1; } }

    public CSVItem(string accNo, DateTime date, double value, int sNo)
    {
        Value = value;            
        Date = date;
        AccountNumber = accNo;
        SNO = sNo;
    }


}
```

I read a CSV, and I make a List of Type CSV Item with about 500k items. Then I try to sort using the default Order By method of the list, and try to return the list from the sorted collection. Here is the code:

```
List<CSVItem> items = new List<CSVItem>();

 // ---- some code to read csv and load into items collection

 List<CSVItem> vItems = items.OrderBy(r1 => r1.AccountNumber).ThenBy(r1 => r1.Date).ToList();
```

It is like taking forever to sort and then convert the collection back to a list. Well I have certainly tried loading about a million records previously and never had such -no response- from Linq Sorting ever and it is kind of driving me crazy. Any help or suggestion on where I can look for finding the problem?

Comment: I don't know how much this will help, but you may want to cache the result of Year instead of doing the calculation each time.

Comment: @skaz But seems he did not use Year to sort....

Comment: @PaulZahra yes, you are correct. It is actually ToList() which is making it slower. If I don't do ToList() it is totally instant and wicked fast. But I need a list coz I need to loop through the records too for some operations. I am unable to find what can be the reason behind this slowness. If you guys can suggest me, I may be able to find a workaround or make it faster.

Comment: @Skaz, Year is not being used at all for sorting so I dont know if it makes a difference at all.

Comment: How long do you mean by "forever"?

Comment: The ToList() is actually evaluating the query so slowdown is obvious tbh... Try using IEnumerable vItems = items.OrderBy(r1 => r1.AccountNumber).ThenBy(r1 => r1.Date) .. you can still iterate vItems... or try IOrderedEnumerable<CSVItem> vItems = items.OrderBy(r1 => r1.AccountNumber).ThenBy(r1 => r1.Date)

Comment: Also, you may consider the use of `SortedSet`

Comment: @Vikas using IOrderedEnumerable<CSVItem> vItems = items.OrderBy(r1 => r1.AccountNumber).ThenBy(r1 => r1.Date) you wont have to call ToList() when ordering.

Comment: You can use [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of LINQ OrderBy

Comment: using AsParallel worked. I have no idea why. But it did :)

Comment: @Nacho Several tests already showed, Sort is slower than the OrderBy.

Comment: Also, isn't it (i mean icomparable sorting) even slower when we have multiple columns to sort with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AsParallel()` to your advantage.

```
List<CSVItem> vItems = items.AsParallel().OrderBy(r1 => r1.AccountNumber).ThenBy(r1 => r1.Date).ToList();
```

The question arised, if the parallelization of `OrderBy()` does have *side-effects* if it's followed by a `ThenBy()`.

When does the `AsParallel()` split the `IEnumerable`? There are 2 possible answers. Let's take the given query:

```
items.AsParallel().OrderBy(x=>x.Age).ThenBy(x=>x.Size)
```

**Option 1**

The items get split, each part gets ordered by age, then by size and finally merge back into 1 list. Obviously not what we want.

**Option 2**

The items get split, each part gets ordered by age, the items merge back into 1 list. After that, the items get split again, ordered by size and merge back into 1 list. That's what we want.

I created a little example to check, which one is true.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestItem> items = new List<TestItem>();
        List<TestItem> itemsNonParallel = new List<TestItem>();

        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 1, Size = 12 });
        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 2, Size = 1 });
        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 5, Size = 155 });
        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 23, Size = 42 });
        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 7, Size = 32 });
        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 9, Size = 22 });
        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 34, Size = 11 });
        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 56, Size = 142 });
        items.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 300, Size = 13 });

        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 1, Size = 12 });
        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 2, Size = 1 });
        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 5, Size = 155 });
        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 23, Size = 42 });
        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 7, Size = 32 });
        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 9, Size = 22 });
        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 34, Size = 11 });
        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 56, Size = 142 });
        itemsNonParallel.Add(new TestItem() { Age = 300, Size = 13 });

        foreach (var item in items.AsParallel().OrderBy(x => x.Age).ThenBy(x => x.Size))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Age: {item.Age}     Size: {item.Size}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

        foreach (var item in itemsNonParallel.OrderBy(x => x.Age).ThenBy(x => x.Size))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Age: {item.Age}     Size: {item.Size}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();        
    }
}

public class TestItem
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**

`AsParallel()` does what we want. It first processes the `OrderBy()` parallel, merges back the list and then moves on to the next query, in our case `ThenBy()`. I tested this multiple times and always the same result.

Comment: Thanks @greenhoorn. It worked. Can you explain the concept behind it? It is so fast...

Comment: @Vikas I don't know how it works exactly, but the method call AsParallel() splits your original list into several parts. Each part is being processed by an own thread. On dual-core cpus the performance is doubled. But note, this only works for time-taking lists. For small lists AsParallel() is about 200 times slower! Because of the additional method call.

Comment: way to go buddy, thanks for the valuable information.

Comment: Btw this is no longer simple linq... it's now PLINQ .. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/asparallel .. also on single core cpus the performance will be roughly the same as without AsParallel()... on dual core it's doubled... on quad core + it may be improved further.

Comment: @PaulZahra Single-core cpus can't perform parallel tasks (normally). That's why there is no performance enhancement. I don't know a single person which is using less than 2 cores ;-)

Comment: @greenhoorn indeed, I just put the info here for completeness.

Comment: @Vikas If I were you I'd check the resulting order to ensure it is as you want... run that check multiple times... the following implies that your orderby and thenby may be run in different orders... "The query partitions the source into tasks that are executed asynchronously on multiple threads. The order in which each task completes depends not only on the amount of work involved to process the elements in the partition, but also on external factors such as how the operating system schedules each thread." See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Vikas The above quote implies to me that for example AsParellel().Where would work fine... but AsParallel().OrderBy().ThenBy() may give different results depending on several factors.

Comment: @PaulZahra That's something I was thinking of too. Maybe silly, but I was assuming AsParallel() is processing only the method itself (i.e. OrderBy()) parallel and then moves on to the next method and does the same. Otherwise it would not be very useful per design. But could you please check this Vikas?

Comment: @greenhoorn Indeed, it depends wholly on how it is splitting... e.g. if it simply splits the 'source' meaning the 500k records and orders them on seperate threads then merges them it's fine... but if it splits the 'source' meaning the orderby() and the thenby() issues could arise.

Comment: @greenhoorn see if anyone can answer the question outright...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340798/how-does-asparallel-split-its-source

Comment: Ok, so just to update. I had a CSV with about 200k rows, and I prepared my results using AsParallel and without AsParallel. Did lot of sum, max, min and sorting to prepare my results. And in my test, the results came same.