# Linq Query Performance issue on large number of records using C#

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I'm having web application which is built into angularJs, C#, Linq etc.
I'm having almost 2,00,000 lac records on production environment.

Almost each columns have filters (Asc/Desc on click of column), I'm also having pagination and displaying 25 records per page.

Now the problem is that when I'm trying to filter records using ID column (Primary key in DB table) is working fast as expected but other table columns filters working too slow to respond.

Few of those columns are dynamic calculated from C# code and few of them such as Address, Agent Name etc coming from other joined table.

I'm going to post my little code which could help someone to understand the scenario.

```
//Do the sorting
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.sortColumn))
 {
   switch (r.sortColumn)
   {
    case "id":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.TransactionID) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.TransactionID);
        break;
    case "created":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.StatusDate ?? x.DateCreated) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.StatusDate ?? x.DateCreated);
        break;
    case "salePrice":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.SalePrice) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.SalePrice);
        break;
    case "agent":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(z => z.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().tblAgent.LastName) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(z => z.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().tblAgent.LastName);
        break;
    case "state":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.Property_State) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.Property_State);
        break;
    case "sob":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.SOBid) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.SOBid);
        break;
    case "branch":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.tblBranch.BranchName) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.tblBranch.BranchName);
        break;
    case "addr1":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.Property_Address1) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.Property_Address1);
        break;
    case "mls":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.MLSno) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.MLSno);
        break;
    case "side":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.SideRepresentingID) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.SideRepresentingID);
        break;
    case "statusName":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.CurrentStatusId) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.CurrentStatusId);
        break;
    case "sentToAccountingDate":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.tblStatusTransactions.Where(y => x.CurrentStatusId == 5 && y.NewStatusID == 5).OrderByDescending(z => z.EntryID).FirstOrDefault().StatusChangeDateTime) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.tblStatusTransactions.Where(y => x.CurrentStatusId == 5 && y.NewStatusID == 5).OrderByDescending(z => z.EntryID).FirstOrDefault().StatusChangeDateTime);
        break;
    case "settleDate":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.SettlementDate) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.SettlementDate);
        break;
    case "settlementActual":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.SettlementDate_Actual) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.SettlementDate_Actual);
        break;
    case "remitAmount":
        if (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC")
        {
            t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(y => y.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().Agent_ServiceFee)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(y => y.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().Agent_GrossGCC)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.AdminFeeAmtClient)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(y => y.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().ParnershipPercentage)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(y => y.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().Agent_Bonus);
        }
        else
        {
            t = t.OrderBy(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(y => y.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().Agent_ServiceFee)
                .ThenBy(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(y => y.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().Agent_GrossGCC)
                .ThenBy(x => x.AdminFeeAmtClient)
                .ThenBy(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(y => y.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().ParnershipPercentage)
                .ThenBy(x => x.tblTransactionAgentDetails.Where(y => y.isPrimary).FirstOrDefault().Agent_Bonus);
        }
        break;
    case "listPrice":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.ListPrice) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.ListPrice);
        break;
    case "lender":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.tblCompany.CompanyName) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.tblCompany.CompanyName);
        break;
    case "title":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.tblCompany.CompanyName) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.tblCompany.CompanyName);
        break;
    case "commissionStatus":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.CommissionStatus) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.CommissionStatus);
        break;
    case "fAssignedTo":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.FAssignedTo) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.FAssignedTo);
        break;
    case "EMDStatus":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.EMDStatus) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.EMDStatus);
        break;
    case "processingSchedule":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProcessingSchedule) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.ProcessingSchedule);
        break;
    case "fileManagement":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.FileManagement) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.FileManagement);
        break;
    case "trackerStatus":
        t = (r.sortDirection.ToUpper() == "DESC") ? t = t.OrderByDescending(x => x.TrackerStatus) : t = t.OrderBy(x => x.TrackerStatus);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
   }

  //Execute the data
var final = t.Skip(r.perPage * r.index).Take(r.perPage).ToList();
```

Further, I also did some research on this but didn't get appropriate working solution yet.

Here was similar question but this isn't working for me: [linq order by taking really long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338384/linq-order-by-taking-really-long-time)

Any type of help would be really appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Feels like a typically database performance optimization problem and less of EF. So look at the SQL actually send to the database. And use the tools that are hopefully provided with the database you use that does index recommendations for those SQLs.

Comment: When I debug the C# code and then copy/paste dynamic SQL query into DB then it's also returning results faster then entity framework.

Comment: What type is t?

Comment: ID works fast because it is a key.  Other columns are not key and will work slower.  Add a key to the other columns will speed up results.

Comment: The database will need an index to be able to quickly sort on any given property. Without an index it would need to do a "full table scan". But having to many indices can hurt insert performance.

Comment: You really have `20 000 000 000` records? Also, please don't use local words like `lac` since not everyone understands what it means, and I might be misunderstanding you also...

Comment: Use Keyset [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination) - it's more faster.

Comment: Dude, I don't mean to be rude, but this code is crap. Obviously, you get paid for the number of lines of code. But if this is not the case, it can be rewritten much shorter. Create a new topic asking for a code review. And be sure to specify the exact version of EF you are using. In EF Core with the help of `EF.Property` method the code can be shortened by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem where you try to design a system to be too flexible. You would have the exact same problem building raw SQL queries if you give the option to users to sort and filter by anything and everything without a consideration of how the database would actually be optimized to accommodate that. As mentioned databases use indexes to help optimize sorting and searching. Adding indexes to columns being used as filters or sorting can improve searching behavior, but indexes themselves are sorted, which affects how useful they are in queries that filter or sort using them. However, slapping in indexes for every column doesn't come without significant cost. Indexes take up a considerable amount of space, and they need to be refreshed whenever rows are added, removed, or updated, which takes time, especially with how large indexes will get against very large tables.

The solution to issues like this is generally to sit down with the business analyst/product owner to go over what end users are actually going to use for searching and provide just the most useful, common search capabilities with supporting indexes. As opposed to trying to design a system that caters to every possible whim of a user that never really get used, but sit there waiting to grind the database to a halt should someone decide to use them intentionally or accidentally.

> Few of those columns are dynamic calculated from C# code and few of
> them such as Address, Agent Name etc coming from other joined table.

Filtering and sorting against joined entities is not usually an issue, but the same indexing rules apply. What can be a big problem depends on what you mean by "dynamic calculated from C# code" and how you have EF configured or might explicitly invoke client-side evaluation. For example, if you have properties in your entities that are calculated/composed in C# code such as calling a .Net or custom function, and want to sort or filter by those calculated properties in the Linq query, by default EF Core will throw an exception when it encounters one of these scenarios. If you have reverted EF's behavior to use a warning instead of an exception (not recommended) or explicitly client-side evaluate by inserting a `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` then the query will "work" but it will have huge performance implications as the query will execute and start loading all entities it might filter up to that point into memory before attempting to continue the C#-based filtering. At the end you will get your 1 page of results, but EF will have loaded many thousands or millions of rows into memory. Look over your queries carefully for any use of `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()` anywhere prior to the `.Skip()`/`.Take()`. To avoid serious performance issues you need to remove these, rewriting the filtering/sorting to use basic mapped properties even if they look uglier/more complex than a simple helper method. The EF Configuration to look out for in a project is if your DbContext `.OnConfiguring()` handler has the following as part of the optionsBuilder:

```
.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning))
```

If your DbContext has this set, I would strongly recommend removing it so that client-side evaluation returns to throwing an exception, and dealing with those scenarios properly to remove the need for client-side evaluation.

Comment: Any code example would helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: Not much I can add, the first thing is to determine what filters and sorting the business will actually use, or use most often and limiting the filtering and sorting option selections in the front end and code to just those options, then ensure there are supporting indexes in the database.  The second involves searching for any calls to `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` that appear before you try getting your page of results. If you have examples you want help to remove we would need to see them specifically.